# Wordpress: ignore a function from functions.php in a template

Tags: php, wordpress

If functions.php has a function written like

```
function scripts() {
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect;
```

can I ignore this in a template I'm creating? I'm picking up this project from another developer and I'm not really sure I can remove this from functions.php due to the fact there are other templates that use the mobile style. I don't need to so I'd rather just ignore the mobile stylesheet all together.

Comment: if the function is declared, but not used, it won't be a problem unless you declare a new function with the same name. Do a search and see where it is used. If it is never invoked, you should be safe. If it is, you need to understand what it does to decide what to do.

Comment: Ah, I think I found it; it's added in `functions.php` with `add_action('scripts');`. Otherwise it doesn't show up anywhere in my template.